# can't download file of which size is bigger than 2GB

Tags: filesystem, browser, downloads

I can use a simple C program to generate 2GB+ file. But when I try to download a 3GB file through browser, it stops at 2GB.

I tried `Chrome`, `Firefox` and `Opera`. No one can download the file of which size is bigger than 2GB. What am I supposed to do?

(my file system is `ext4`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had many problems in the past with trying to download larger files through browsers. You can open up a terminal and use wget.... with -c option. If it stops downloading at the 2 GB limit you have been reaching, just up arrow to the last command you just entered, and hit enter again. Your download will resume.

```
wget -c <download url goes here>
```

[image: Showing wget resume SS1]

Here I am downloading a small DVD as an example. (I know it's not larger than 2 GB's but this will work regardless of file size, as long as you have remaining disk space to download it to).

[image: Showing wget resume SS2]

I hit CTRL + C to stop the download.

[image: Showing wget resume SS3]

I up arrowed to the previous command, and after hitting enter, the download resumes!

Hope this helps!!