# Stops downloading large file after 2GB

Tags: networking, files, filesystem, downloads, resource-limiting

I've had an issue downloading large files where the download halts after each 2GB chunk of data for a while now (possibly from the very start of using Kubuntu).

For example, I am downloading a >8GB file with wget and have had to restart the download three times (with `wget -c url_here`)

`95%[++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++======================================>        ]   8,03G  1,82MB/s    eta 2m 13s`

I've refreshed the system logs (using KSystemLog) before and after to see if it threw some error. But nothing was printed out.

I've also seen the issue here:
[can't download file of which size is bigger than 2GB](https://askubuntu.com/q/104625/1290978)
but the root cause wasn't discussed or solved.

In an attempt to narrow down the issue, I tried downloading from the same source and network on a Windows laptop and that worked without halting indefinitely. But neither my Kubuntu desktop setup, nor Ubuntu server is able to download >2GB files.

It also happens to the browser and in a Windows VM on my Kubuntu desktop.

I've also noticed torrenting large files work fine. So perhaps it has to do with a download limit per connection?

Here's a bit of generic info that might help:

```
(base) ab@desktop:~/Downloads$ uname -a
Linux desktop 5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 02:35:03 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

(base) ab@desktop:~/Downloads$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

(base) ab@desktop:~$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 63437
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 63437
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

(base) ab@desktop:~$ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME   FSTYPE   MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs /snap/core18/2074
loop1  squashfs /snap/snapd/12159
loop2  squashfs /snap/core18/2066
loop3  squashfs /snap/snapd/12398
loop4  squashfs /snap/spotify/46
sda             
└─sda1 ext4     
sdb             
├─sdb1 vfat     /boot/efi
├─sdb2 ext4     /
└─sdb3 ext4     /home
sdc             
└─sdc1 xfs      /run/timeshift/backup
```

Video demonstration:
https://youtu.be/24yO6NxwFgQ

Any ideas on what might be wrong are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have a *fs* that can support >2GB files; ie. could the download be stopping due to disk IO error as the data cannot be saved...  What *file-system* are using trying to save the files too?  2GB is one of the limits for certain *fs*

Comment: Good question guiverc. I added the relevant info. I'm using ext4 for my home directory, and I ran the download command at ~. I think ext4 is able to handle >2gb files. I'll see if I can make a demonstrative video of what's going on today.

Comment: It could also be your router :)

Comment: Thanks for writing, Rinzwind ^^ I did try to rule that out by using my windows computer to download a >2GB file. I actually tried it again though, and it's doing the same as it does on Ubuntu. Could perhaps be due to using a 4G router, but it's probably not Ubuntu that's the issue then. I'm going to try a few more things. Otherwise, it is how it is.